# xamlparseexception when i tried to use notifyicon

Tags: wpf, exception

so i've been trying to make use of [hardcodet wpfnotifyicon](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2#tutorial1), but i get this exception when the program reaches the mainwindow's InitializeComponent

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Nastavení vlastnosti Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.TaskbarIcon.IconSource vyvolalo výjimku. Číslo řádku 13 a pozice na řádku 10.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at clipboardDialer.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\STUDENT\Source\Repos\clipboardDialer\clipboardDialer\MainWindow.xaml:line 1

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentException: The supplied image source 'pack://application:,,,/rsrc/settingsIcon.ico' could not be resolved.
```

here's the xaml for the main window, note that i don't get any errors

```
<Window x:Class="clipboardDialer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:clipboardDialer"
        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" MinWidth="640" MinHeight="190"
        ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden">

    <Grid>
        <tb:TaskbarIcon IconSource="C:\Users\STUDENT\Source\Repos\clipboardDialer\clipboardDialer\rsrc\settingsIcon.png">
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>
                <Border
            BorderThickness="2"
            CornerRadius="4"
            Opacity="0.8"
            Width="160"
            Height="40">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFBDBDBD" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFAFAF" Offset="0.797"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF6F6F6" Offset="0.503"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <TextBlock
                Text="hello world"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                />
                </Border>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayToolTip>

        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(yes i know i should be using a relative path but this is just there so i could find out that the rsrc folder not being someplace it should be is not the issue)

i also tried to set the build action of the ico as a resource but the exception remains

Comment: Did you mark the settingsIcon.ico file build action as a resource?

Comment: @KevinCook what? how do i do that? i've never heard of that before